# Why is Xubuntu 17.04 refusing to update my software?

Tags: xubuntu, 17.04

Why is Xubuntu 17.04 refusing to update my software? My internet is working fine. This is really frustrating. It also doesn't even show update possibility to 17.10. I get a note to check the internet, but the internet service is fine. It's working for everything else.

Comment: What have you tried ? Please update your question with commands and results of your efforts.

Comment: Xubuntu 17.04 is now past its end-of-life. Please upgrade to 17.10 by following the instructions at the link above.

Comment: Also, if you want more than 9 months of support, you should stick to LTS releases, which are supported for 5 years.